# basic bash script function adding variables

Tags: bash, function, variables, math, scripting

I am trying to create a function that converts a time string to total minutes ie "11:22" would return 682

```
str_to_min(){
    ARR_T=$(echo $1 | tr ":" "\n")
    HOUR=${ARR_T[0]}
    MINUTE=${ARR_T[1]}
    let MIN=(60*$HOUR)
    let MIN=($MIN+$MINUTE)
    #echo total minutes $MIN
    return $MIN
}

str_to_min "11:22"
```

but i keep getting the following error:

./find_service_to_display.sh: line 5: let: MIN=(60*11: missing `)' (error token is "11")
./find_service_to_display.sh: line 6: let: MIN=(11: missing`)' (error token is "11")

Comment: Have you tried to use `echo` or `printf` for debugging?

Comment: The reason it doesn't work is that `ARR_T=$(echo $1 | tr ":" "\n")` doesn't create an array, it creates a string variable that happens to have a newline in the middle. Then when you use it, having a newline in the middle of an expression causes ... problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
str_to_min() {
    local hours=${1%:*};
    local mins=${1#*:};
    echo $((hours * 60 + mins));
}
```

You probably want 'echo' rather than 'return' unless you really want a return status (which acts like a program exit code).

Answer (score 0):

```
str_to_min() { echo $1 | awk -F: '{print 60*$1 + $2}'; }
```

Note that this does not return the value, but prints it to stdout.   You really cannot return the value, since return values must be in the range 0-255, and will be truncated to that range.  This function instead always returns zero to indicate success.  It would probably be a good idea to return an error value if the string is not in the correct format.  One idea for simple checking would be:

```
str_to_min() { echo "$1" | awk -F: '/^[0-9]+:[0-9]+$/{ print 60*$1 + $2; exit(0)} 
    {exit 1}'; }
```